# ¿Como puedo almacenar los caracteres introducidos en un JTextArea en una variable?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy aprendiendo java y me he visto en un problema al crear un login, quiero almacenar los datos que un usuario introduzca en un JTextArea en una variable, pero no se me almacena, y cuando le de a un boton que lo compare con un nombre que le he puesto yo(ya que todavia no me se manejar con bases de datos) lo he probado de varias maneras y no consigo hacerlo, no se si alomejor con JTextArea no se puede y tendria que usar otra cosa. Gracias de antemano

**He echo:**

```
JTextArea areausuario = new JTextArea("", 1, 16);

String ususario=areausuario.getText();

//Comprobar que hay en la variable
System.out.println(usuario);
```

Comment: Añade lo que has intentado para ayudarte de una mejor manera.

Comment: Creo que estoy viendo un problema de lógica. ¿Qué error te marca? ¿Supongo que ninguno? ¿Tienes la línea `ususario=areausuario.getText();` inmediatamente después de la creación del JTextArea? Intenta poner esto: `areaUsuario.setText("Una prueba"); usuario = areaUsuario.getText(); System.out.println(usuario)` Eso debe imprimir `Una prueba`.

Comment: También puedes crear el objeto con algo escrito y hacer tu prueba: `JTextArea areausuario = new JTextArea("Datos de prueba", 1, 16);`

Comment: Lo he conseguido poniendo un setText, pero no se por que al poner que el texto sea introducido por el usuario me falla.

Answer (score 1):

El error que tuve fue que puse un botón para confirmar si el usuario introducido era correcto, pero almacene lo que había en el JTextArea, antes del ActionListener, que pasa, al hacer eso, la variable en la que guardaba el texto introducido por el usuario estaba vacía y al pulsar el botón no cambiaba su valor.

```
    class EventoConfirmar implements ActionListener {


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //Parte que tenia fuera del ActionListener 
        usuariointro=areausuario.getText().trim();

        if (usuariointro.equals(usuario1.getNombreUsuario())){

            System.out.println("Uusario correcto");

        }else {

            System.out.println("Usuario incorrecto");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: te recomiendo aceptar tu propia respuesta. saludos.